# Specify RMI endpoint address when having two interfaces

Tags: java, rmi

I have an rmi server on a box with two public interfaces. When a client connects, it always returns the wrong ip address in the `UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.x.x.x:xxxx` .... The connection from the client goes to the other interface with ip `10.x.x.x`. Does anybody know how to solve this? I do not want to specify the ip when binding the stub. It works then, but I would like it to listen on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`).

If I specify `java.rmi.server.hostname=myhostname` and use a `RMIServerSocketFactory` to create a `ServerSocket[addr=myhostname/10.x.x.x,localport=xxxx]`, it still returns the `192.x.x.x` adress to the client as remote endpoint. Weird enough I have two `UnicastRemoteObjects` objects on diffrerent ports and one of them returns the right address, the other not.

Any Ideas how to make it to return the endpoint with the ip of the interface the connection was made to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the java.rmi.server.hostname property is for. Set it at the exporting JVM to whatever IP address you want the clients to use to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I would like to automatically return the ip of the interface the client uses. So that I can have clients that use a local network address and others connect over the internet. Or at least I would like only to specify a hostname that is set in /etc/hosts, without having to explicitly setting the ip in the app.

Comment: Ok, actually it works with the hostname. The problem was, that I set the java.rmi.server.hostname before binding to the stub, but after creating the UnicastRemoteObject. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hmm, no, sorry, its still not working. For some reason, it does work for one the connections, but the other still gets the wrong ip address.

Comment: Ok, not sure what happend. But probably it still had to do with this setting. Thanks again!